# Some bars are rendering with different width than others in c3 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a stacked bar chart created using C3 chart.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                json: d,
                keys: {
                    x: 'Date',
                    value: ['Other', 'P2', 'P1']
                },
                type: 'bar',
                groups: [
                    ['P1', 'P2', 'Other']
                ],
                order: false,
                names: {
                    P1: 'P1',
                    P2: 'P2',
                    Other: 'Other'
                }
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 1 / (((d.length - 3) / 3 * 2) + 0.6)
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%b-%d',
                        //count: 7,
                        culling: {
                            max:3
                        }
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    min: 0,
                    padding: {
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            grid: {
                y: {
                    lines: [{ value: 0 }]
                }
            }
        });
```

[Please check it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jyothishmb/fq58qfbt/13/)

But sometimes the bars are showing different width. Is there anything wrong in what I am doing.

What I am getting in some screens is like the following image.

[image]

Is there any problem in the width calculation. Please correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Looks good on google chrome. On firefox, bars are not visible and in IE, bar colors are very light.

Comment: Please adjust the div width in js fiddle. May it will reproduce the issue. Thanks for looking the issue. I am trying to update the fiddle. But not saving.